# can't redirect new page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

can someone help me redirect to new page in javascript?

here is my code

```
<p style=float:right;><font color="green"><a href=""  onclick='return validate1();'>Delete</a></font></p>


function validate1()
{



var j1=0;
     for(var i=0; i <document.Check.clickeduser.length;i++)
        {
            if(document.Check.clickeduser[i].checked)
                {
                    if(j1==0)
                    {   
                        total1 +=document.Check.clickeduser[i].value;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        total1 +="|"+document.Check.clickeduser[i].value;
                    }
                j1++;
                }

        }

if(total1=="")
{


alert("Select user to Delete"); 
return false;

}
else
{


var where_to= confirm("Do you really want to delete??");

 if(where_to==true)
 {

 window.location = '<?php echo $redirect ?>locations.php?locationid='+total1;


 }

 else
 {
 total1="";


     document.Check.checkall.checked = false;

//alert("alert");
 for(var j=0; j<=document.Check.clickeduser.length;j++)
    {
     document.Check.clickeduser[j].checked = false;
    }


 }

return true;
}


}
```

here window.location = 'locations.php?locationid='+total1; could n't redirect this link.

i don't know what's wrong please guide me

Thanks for advance

Comment: what your $redirect contain add http:// in redirect element or add  'http://'+'<?php echo $redirect ?>locations.php?locationid='+total1;

Comment: $redirect contains:http://app.ologie.us/app/admin/

Comment: add http:// to your link and than try. you have missed out the semicolon in echo statement.

Comment: what is the use of the **|** in the statement total1 +="|"+document.Check.clickeduser[i].value;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
window.location = '<?php echo $redirect ?>locations.php?locationid='+total1;
```

Try this

```
window.location = 'locations.php?locationid='+total1;  // why you need $redirect;
```

You can try this

```
//There was no ';' in <?php echo ?>
window.location = '<?php echo $redirect; ?>locations.php?locationid='+total1;
```

Comment: ok thanks for response i try this it redirect only locations.php only

Comment: when user click confirm box ==true then it redirect to locations.php?locationid but here it redirect to only locations.php only

Comment: please initialise the **var total1 = ''** in your validate1 funtion.